# Tiller is installed but not found by Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, jenkins-x

**Background**
I have kubernetes installed in clustered mode. 
All nodes are up and running 
I want to use jenkins-x to get ease of deployment. 
Now jenkins-x uses Helm to do this job; Helm comes up with client and server architecture.

Helm setup can be achieved by following two ways:-

**Using jenkins-x**

```
jx install --username <username>
```

**Standalone Helm**

```
helm init
```

This helps to setup itsserver (Tiller), by putting it in pod of Kubernetes.

**Whats issue**

The issue is when I use first approach it does Tiller installation and later get failed by saying 'Tiller is available but not up and running'.

```
Created ClusterRoleBinding tiller
retrying after error:existing tiller deployment found but not running, please check the kube-system namespace and resolve any issues
```

> Second approach also gets fail in similar path

It also does the Tiller installation but it does not find Tiller when I'm trying to list it.

```
helm ls
```

Error: could not find tiller

**So essence of issue is** :

It does Tiller installation but fails it in finding later.

```
helm init
```

**Warning: Tiller is already installed in the cluster.**

```
helm ls
```

**Error: could not find tiller**

Answer (score 4):

I just went ahead and installed both helm and Jx with no problem. So, I don't know how to resolve your issue, but you can install it as below, and should work.

Installing Helm:

```
$ wget https://kubernetes-helm.storage.googleapis.com/helm-v2.9.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz
$ tar xzvf helm-v2.9.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz
$ cd linux-amd64/
$ sudo cp helm /usr/local/bin/helm
$ helm init
```

Installing Jx

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx/releases/download/v1.2.98/jx-linux-amd64.tar.gz | tar xzv 
$ sudo mv jx /usr/local/bin
```

Making Tiller cluster-admin role:

```
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-admin \
     --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
     --serviceaccount=kube-system:default
```

Checking it works:

```
$ helm install --name prometheus stable/prometheus
$ helm ls
```

> prometheus       1               Sun Jun  3 09:47:12 2018        DEPLOYED        prometheus-6.7.0        default

Comment: @Kundan I have 3.

Comment: After some more debugging I have figured out that it could be because of replicas are not getting created and I believe that percolates to tiller is not up and running.
I could not see any of secrets assigned while creating replicas individually. by issuing "kubctl get sa" command.
Also could you please post how many pods were there before and after jx install --username root

Answer (score 2):

there may be a problem with the tiller pod starting either due to resources or RBAC. Try these commands:

```
kubectl get deploy -n kube-system
kubectl get node -n kube-system
```

that might give more of a clue. If you can find a tiller pod thats failing mabe

```
kubectl describe pod tiller-1234 -n kube-system
```